# LINQ compare object variables & aggregate result

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following problem and just learned about LINQ.

I have a list of objects containing two values: username & ip address.

E.g:

Username / IP:

- **hans              192.168.0.1**
- **hans              192.168.0.1**
- **peter             192.168.0.2**
- **maria             192.168.0.3**
- **maria             192.168.0.1**

And i want to filter out the usernames that use 2 different ip-addresses - in this case my desired result would be:

**maria - 192.168.0.3 - 192.168.0.1**

Is this possible with LINQ?
so far I removed the duplicates & did some other queries but sadly am stuck at this point. Every hint is appreciated!

Comment: Before thinking about  LINQ, ask yourself "how would I do that **without** linq"? There are so many badly designed linq-queries outside just to have a linq-statement, whereas a good old-fashioned loop achieves the exact same results while being easy to write and to understand.

Comment: Anyway: what exactly is your data-structure? A list of strings? Or a list of `User`-instances where every `User` has a `Name` and an `IP`? Please provide what you´ve achieved so far, which in particular includes your current code.

Comment: To add slightly to @HimBromBeere point, There's often this impression, that linq is faster than a for loop, it's not. It does the same iterations under the hood as a for loop does. When you add the good old *"Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."* and given that a for loop is often more readable then think carefully about reaching for "linq" all the time

Comment: @HimBromBeere, Liam good point, i will look into it and evaluate, maybe a loop fits better. It is actually a list of objects that have the same structure as "SomeBody" assumed in his answer. Thanks for your input guys, appreciated,  pretty new to SO, next time I will provide some more infos/code, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your object Looks like this:

```
public class MyType
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string IP {get;set;}
    }
```

The following query should return strings that look like the one in your question:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.Select(y => y.IP).Distinct().Count() == 2).Select(x => x.Key + " - " + string.Join(" - ", x.Select(y => y.IP)));
```

Via GroupBy, your grouping the objects by their Name. Then you check if there are Groups, where the distinct enumerable of IP addresses has two elements. In the last step, with the select you Format the string as above.

But I agree with Liam's comment: I am not really sure if this code is more readable than a non-LINQ Version of it.